# Convert Try to Future and recoverWith as Future

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I have a `Try` that throws Exception. I want that `Try` to become a `Future` so I will be able to `recoverWith`.

How can I convert the `Try` into a `Future` without handling any exceptions in the `Try` (just in the Future with recover)?

*note that Await is needed to test the result of your future*

The code sample demonstrates what I had in mind but it also throws once reached (`new RuntimeException("-------failed-------")` is what I get)

```
val t = Try(throw new RuntimeException("my"))

val resF : Future[String] = if (t.isSuccess)
  Future.successful(t.get)
else
  Future.failed(new RuntimeException("-------failed-------"))

val resFWithRecover = resF.recoverWith{
  case NonFatal(e) =>
    Future.successful("recoveredWith")
}
Await.result(resFWithRecover, Duration("5s"))
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> ... how do convert `Try` to `Future` without handling any exception in the `Try`?

Use `Future.fromTry`.

```
scala> val t = Try(throw new RuntimeException("my"))
t: scala.util.Try[Nothing] = Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: my)

scala> val resF = Future.fromTry(t)
resF: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@57cf54e1

scala> resF.recoverWith{
     |   case NonFatal(e) =>
     |     Future.successful("recoveredWith")
     | }
res5: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1b75c2e3
```

Comment: running: val res = Await.result(resF, Duration("1s"))   , will throw the exception

Comment: @ozma, don't `Await` on `resF`.  Instead await of what `recoverWith` returns. In other words, `val resRW = resF.recoverWith{...}`, and then `Await.result(resRW, ...`.

Comment: @jwvh that is what I do (added it to the code sample now)

Comment: @ozma, your code sample doesn't use the `fromTry()` as m-z has suggested.  My tests indicate that m-z's code works.  You just have to `Await` on the proper `Future`, i.e. not the one returned from `fromTry()` but the one returned from `recoverWith()` **after** `fromTry()`.

Comment: @ozma First of all, why _bother_ using `Future`s if you're just going to block with `Await`? That makes no sense.  Second, if you're going to use `Await`, you need to do it on the last `Future`, that is, the result of calling `recoverWith`. In my example you would await on `res5`, _not_ `resF`. i.e. `Await.result(resF.recoverWith { ... }, Duration.Inf)`. Futures are immutable. Recovering `resF` does not change `resF`, it creates a new `Future`.

Comment: @m-z, our server uses some that api on startup (where we want it to block with Await) and on other stages of its life-cycle. it must be Future and and behave like one. sure, I would wait on res5 too.

Comment: @m-z, Thanks, It works fine! I had a typo as you've offered.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to introduce *Future* if all you want to do is to use *recoverWith* (kind of like *flatMap*) on your *Try* object.

You could so something like the following:

```
val t = Try[String](throw new RuntimeException("my"))
val u = t.recoverWith{
  case e => Success(s"ignoring exception ${e.getLocalizedMessage}")
}
u.foreach(println(_))
```

This results in the following output to the console:

```
ignoring exception my
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was not my question. I need to keep an interface that returns Future and I need it to behave like one.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // you need to provide your try with type information in lhs
 // as the rhs is not providing any type info
 val t: Try[String] = Try(throw new RuntimeException("my"))

 // Now you can easily get a Future[String] from this Try[String]
 val f = Future.fromTry(t)

 // or you can use pattern matching
 val f2 = t match {
   case Success(str) => Future.succesful(str)
   case Failure(ex) => Future.failed(ex)
 }
```

Comment: I guess, you meant "f2 = f match {...". It did not compile for me. please add the complete example with the right imports. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can `recoverWith` on `Try` also

Use `map` and `recover` methods on `Try` to produce `Future.successful` and `Future.failed` respectively and then `get` on `Try`

```
val future = 
 Try {
   throw new Exception("explosion")
 }.map { result =>
   Future.successful(result)
 }.recover { case th =>
   Future.failed(th)
 }.get
```

Using Pattern Matching

```
val future =  
 Try {
  throw new Exception("something")
 } match {
  case Success(value) => Future.successful(value)
  case Failure(th) => Future.failed(th)
 }
```

Comment: please "doSomething()" that "throw" and you not get passed the "}.get"

Comment: thanks. now add recoverWith to that future and "Await". you will still have an exception rather than the recoverd

Answer (score 0):

`Future.fromTry` will run the Try code synchronously. From the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.5/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#fromTry%5BT%5D(result:scala.util.Try%5BT%5D):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D):

> Creates an already completed Future with the specified result or exception.

Since your interface relies on Future, you may want to to run the Try itself asynchronously. This will be more efficient for most use cases. You can do it like this:

```
val f = Future { 
  val t = Try(...)
  t match {
    case Success(value) => value
    case Failure(exception) => throw exception
  }
}

f.recoverWith{...}
```