# How to concurrently create Future from Try?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, future

The scala `Future` has a [`fromTry`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#fromTry%5BT%5D(result:scala.util.Try%5BT%5D):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D) method which

> Creates an already completed Future with the specified result or
> exception.

The problem is that the newly created `Future` is already completed. Is it possible to have the evaluation of the `Try` done concurrently?

As an example, given a function that returns a `Try`:

```
def foo() : Try[Int] = {
  Thread sleep 1000
  Success(43)
}
```

How can the evaluation of `foo` be done concurrently?

A cursory approach would be to simply wrap a `Future` around the function:

```
val f : Future[Try[Int]] = Future { foo() }
```

But the desired return type would be a `Future[Int]`

```
val f : Future[Int] = ???
```

Effectively, **how can the `Try` be flattened within a `Future` similar to the `fromTry` method?**

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581921/convert-try-to-future-and-recoverwith-as-future), however the question & answer wait for the evaluation of the Try before constructing the completed Future.

Comment: As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html) is your friend - `Future.delegate(Future.fromTry(foo()))`

Comment: No, `delegate` isn't it. You are looking for `Future(foo.get)`

Comment: @Dima That only works if the `Try` is `Success`, not `Failure`.

Comment: @RamónJRomeroyVigil nope. It works either way. Try it :)

Comment: @Dima Playing code golf :) I think Luis'  swing is right as `delegate` executes by-name argument on execution context. My swing: `Future(foo()).flatMap(Future.fromTry)`

Comment: @MarioGalic Yeah, ok, I guess, it works. Just don't get why either of your "swings" need two futures. Seems ... excessive :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments,

Scala >= 2.13:

```
val f : Future[Int] = Future.delegate(Future.fromTry(foo()))
```

Scala < 2.13:

```
val f : Future[Int] = Future(foo()).flatMap(Future.fromTry)
```

Answer (score 3):

Least ceremony is probably:

```scala
Future.unit.transform(_ => foo())
```

Special mention goes to @Dima for the suggestion of `Future(foo().get)` which is a bit shorter—but *might* be slightly less readable.